# PHP regex - Take the short one

Tags: php, regex

I have the string: `This is a [[bla]] and i want a [[burp]]` and i need to put in an array the 2 string `[[bla]]` and `[[burp]]`.
The regexp i am trying to use is:

`$pattern = "/\[\[.+\]\]/"`

The problem is that the output is: `[[bla]] and [[burp]]` ,because i suppose it take the first `[[` with the last `]]`
How can i fix the pattern?

Comment: Show some additional code like how you're attempting to do the matches etc and how you're structuring your input array

Comment: You should use what is called "non-greedy matching". Depending on where / how you are using the regex, replace `.+` by `.+?`, add a `?-g` modifier or pass it as an option.

Also, your question is not related to design patterns, probably best to remove that tag.

Comment: Try [lazy matching](http://regex101.com/r/oB6yA2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [ungreedy repitition (lazy) matching](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) here -> `*?` to get only the text between `[[ ]]` and not between `[[ ]] [[ ]]`:

```
$pattern = "/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/"
```

Also you need a [matching group](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) to get only the text between the square brackets and not the brackets itself -> `(.*?)`

Example:

```
$string = "This is a [[bla]] and i want a [[burp]]";
$pattern = "/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/";
preg_match_all($pattern , $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "bla"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "burp"
}
```

Comment: I learn something new today. Thanks. I accepted your answer because is complete and first to write :)

Comment: you are welcome :) Also the other answer is missing to use a subpattern, so it wouldn't work ;)

Answer (score 4):

Make it [ungreedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), see it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?37lmh)

```
/\[\[.+?\]\]/
```

or use a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), see it on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?37lmk)

```
/\[\[[^\]]+\]\]/
```